# TestNG @BeforeGroups(inheritGroups = true) usage

Tags: testng

I have been playing around with TestNG and ran into some behavior I have been unable to understand in that `@BeforeGroups(inheritGroups = true)` does not seem to work. Where `@BeforeSuite(inheritGroups = true)`, `@BeforeTest(inheritGroups = true)`, `@BeforeClass(inheritGroups = true)`, and `@BeforeMethod(inheritGroups = true)`, does work as described in the documentation.

In the code snippet below I am explicitly exercising the `(inheritGroups = true)` annotation parameters for the various `@Before*`. `@BeforeGroups` is the only annotation that is not being invoked when the test is ran. Moreover each of the annotations source code has inheritGroups = true as the default value. Even by not explicitly setting it in the annotation `@BeforeGroups` should be inheriting the class level group set by default.

Code

```
@Test(groups = "acceptance")
public class InheritTest {
    @BeforeSuite(inheritGroups = true)
    public void beforeSuite() {
        System.out.println("I am @BeforeSuite");
    }

    @BeforeTest(inheritGroups = true)
    public void beforeTest() {
        System.out.println("I am @BeforeTest");
    }

    @BeforeGroups
    public void beforeGroupsNoGroup() {
        System.out.println("I am @BeforeGroups");
    }

    @BeforeGroups(inheritGroups = true)
    public void beforeGroupsInherit() {
        System.out.println("I am @BeforeGroups(inheritGroups = true)");
    }

    @BeforeGroups(groups = { "acceptance" })
    public void beforeGroupsGroups() {
        System.out.println("I am @BeforeGroups(groups = {\"acceptance\"}");
    }

    @BeforeClass(inheritGroups = true)
    public void beforeClass() {
        System.out.println("I am @BeforeClass");
    }

    @BeforeMethod(inheritGroups = true)
    public void beforeMethod() {
        System.out.println("I am @BeforeMethod");
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("I am @Test");
    }
}
```

testng.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Test Suite" verbose="1">
    <test name="Run Inherit Test">
        <groups>
            <run>
                <include name="acceptance" />
            </run>
        </groups>
        <classes>
            <class name="InheritTest" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Output

```
I am @BeforeSuite
I am @BeforeTest
I am @BeforeClass
I am @BeforeGroups(groups = {"acceptance"}
I am @BeforeMethod
I am @Test
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has previously been reported as [@BeforeGroups only called if group is specified explicitly · Issue #118 · cbeust/testng](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/118).

You might try commenting there on mentioning [juherr (Julien Herr)](https://github.com/juherr) or [cbeust (Cedric Beust)](https://github.com/cbeust) and linking to this your Stack Overflow question here to see if you can get some traction on confirming that it is an issue and getting it fixed.

Comment: Thanks will leave a comment on that github issue.